# Can we draw a circle that uses Path object? [in arguments, like drawPath()]

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas, android-drawable, undo

I have typed a program which draws on Canvas.

It provides a popup menu which gives 3 Drawing tools as options:

1. Draw line while scratching over screen
2. Draw line based on start and end points on screen
3. Draw a circle

Further, there are options such as:

1. Clear
2. Undo

While performing undo on lines, there's no issue at all because both are based on path. (Uses `List<Path>`).
But here starts the problem. The circle is drawn using Point object. So the issues are:

1. **I cannot make Android distinguish - the order of drawing lines and circles.** Eg: I draw 5 lines, followed by 5 circles (or
   alternatively). There's no intelligence currently to follow their
   order of drawing. Hence undoing canvas with lines and circles drawn
   together leads to mess up.
2. **The current code (not meditated upon in depth yet) needs 2 clicks to undo a circle instead of 1.**

Code shared below (is complex). I tried to dedicate a class to each drawing tool (line,circle) - it worked - except - it didn't draw anything on the Canvas. So, all packed in 1 class back again.

Code:

```
package com.example.orbit_.undofortouch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b1, b2, b3;
    PopupMenu popup;
    int dtool;
    boolean touch,circle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
        final DrawPanel dp = new DrawPanel(this);
        linearLayout.addView(dp);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dp.Clear();
            }
        });

        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dp.Undo();
            }
        });

        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, popup.getMenu());

                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.touch:
                                dtool = 1;
                                break;
                            case R.id.line:
                                dtool = 2;
                                break;
                            case R.id.circle:
                                dtool = 3;
                                break;
                        }

                        Log.v("EDITL:", "Drawtool:".concat(String.valueOf(item.getTitle())));

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Clicked popup menu item " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    }

                });
                popup.show();
            }
        });

   }




class DrawPanel extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

    Bitmap bmp;

    Canvas canvas;
    List<Path> paths, undone;
    List<Point> circlePoints,removeCircles;
    Paint paint;
    Path path;
    Point point;

    public DrawPanel(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attributeSet, defStyle);
    }

    public DrawPanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        path = new Path();
        paths = new ArrayList<>();
        undone = new ArrayList<>();
        circlePoints = new ArrayList<>();
        removeCircles = new ArrayList<>();

        canvas = new Canvas();

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);



        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.desert);
        touch=false;
        circle=false;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        for (Path p : paths)
            canvas.drawPath(p, paint);

        if (touch)
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        touch = false;
        Log.v("Inside onDraw","Circle is".concat(String.valueOf(circle)));

            for (Point p : circlePoints)
                canvas.drawCircle(p.x, p.y, 5, paint);


    }


    float mX, mY,mx,my;
    final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0;



    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        undone.clear();
        Log.v("ONTOUCH:", "Inside DOWN".concat("DOWN-X---:").concat(String.valueOf(x)).concat("**DOWN-Y---:").concat(String.valueOf(y)));
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        mx = x;
        my = y;
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        paths.add(path);
        path = new Path();
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        path.moveTo(mX, mY);
        Log.v("ONTOUCH:", "Inside MOVE".concat("mX:").concat(String.valueOf(mX)).concat("mY:").concat(String.valueOf(mY)));
        Log.v("ONTOUCH:", "Inside MOVE".concat("MOVE-X---:").concat(String.valueOf(x)).concat("**MOVE-Y---:").concat(String.valueOf(y)));
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            path.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        path.lineTo(mX, mY);

        Log.v("MOVE:", " PATH ADDED & New Created");


    }




    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (dtool) {

            case 1:
                touch=true;
                Touch(v, event, x, y);
                break;

            case 2:
                Line(v,event,x,y);
                break;

            case 3:
                Circle(v,event,x,y);
                break;

        }
        Log.v("ONTOUCH:", "OUTSIDE CASE");
        return true;
    }

    public void Line(View v, MotionEvent event, float x, float y) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Touch(View v, MotionEvent event, float x, float y) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();

                break;
        }
    }

    public void Circle(View v, MotionEvent event, float x, float y)
    {   point = new Point();
        point.x = (int)x;
        point.y = (int)y;
        path.moveTo(x,y);
        circle=true;
       if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

           circlePoints.add(new Point(Math.round(point.x), Math.round(point.y)));
           invalidate();
           Log.v("Circle", "Inside Circle");
           circlePoints.add(point);
            paths.add(path);
           
       }
    }

    public void Clear() {
        paths.clear(); //Needs to be experimented
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void Undo() {
        if (paths.size() > 0) {
            undone.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        }
        else if(circlePoints.size()>0)
        {
            removeCircles.add(circlePoints.remove(circlePoints.size()-1));
            invalidate();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

XML Layout Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="top">


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Undo"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tools"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

XML Main Menu code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/touch"
        android:title="Touch"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:title="Circle"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:title="Line"/>



</menu>
```

Comment: `"Can we draw a circle using Path object?"` yes: `Path#addCircle (float x, float y, float radius, Path.Direction dir)`

Comment: Hey, you got me there. I have hence updated the question. If you read the scenario or the purport, you 'll understand my situation to provide a much sympathetic answer :)

Comment: sorry i could only understand the title, and couldn't get the the rest... so actually what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I typed it all there, that's the best way to explain. But in short, a canvas that accepts a line as well as circle and should be able to undo both -IN PROPER ORDER-.

Comment: Another thing, the above code takes 2 clicks to undo a drawn circle. If that is solved (I will try tomorrow), then above issue still remains. Thanks for the efforts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Path.addCircle(float x,float y,float radius, Path.Direction)
```

This simple code did the thing. Because the point the circle is being added will be included in the Path object. And `paths.addPath(path)` simply adds it to the previous list of paths (of drawn lines).

Hence undo becomes easy and natural as well. Hence the solution.

Thanks @pskink for the original solution.

P.S: Today I realized, a break from an unfinished project is not a good practice but in a way it sometimes is to some people, for you are out of familiarity and can now think the normal way which you couldn't before.

Comment: To be clear, this is`path` (the name of your path) not `Path` at the start, or you'll get "Non-static method 'addCircle(float, float, float, android.graphics.Path.Direction)' cannot be referenced from a static context"

Answer (score 0):

Lollipop+

Just make the circle a path as well. You can do a 360 degree Arc, and that'll be a circle. The rip out all the other code for dealing with circles as a different beast.

```
Path path = new Path();
path.addArc(0,0,50,50,0,360);
```

Comment: This should replace something? What problem addresses this block of code? Why does it work?

Comment: He stores a list of paths. Just make the circle a path as well. You can do a 360 degree Arc, and that'll be a circle. The rip out all the other code for dealing with circles as a different beast.

Comment: Sorry for no reply. I am working on 3 projects simultaneously. Once I get back to this one, maybe today or tomorrow, I shall let know. Thanks for the reply. I will try out soon and interact.

Comment: @Tatarize which attribute would the center point be? The circle has to be drawn on a tap. The tap should be the center. And how would radius function?

Comment: How about `Path.addCircle(float x,float y,float radius, Path.Direction)`?

Comment: I must admit that's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Complete Answer:

```
  private Path thumbPath = new Path();


  private void updatePath() {
        float centerX = getWidth()/2.0f;
        float centerY = getHeight()/2.0f;

        thumbPath.reset();
        thumbPath.addCircle(centerX, centerY , thumbRadius-borderThickness , Path.Direction.CW);
        thumbPath.close();

    }

  @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(thumbPath, thumbPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        updatePath();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it maybe also helpful for some people , so I would like to suggest another solution for this

I prefer to do it by my hand :

```
publiv void drawCircle(float center_x, float center_y, float radius, double omega) {
    /*
    Circle with center(a, b)
        
    equation of circle :
    (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = radius^2
        
    x = (+- sqrt( radius^2 - (y - b)^2 )) + a
    y = (+- sqrt( radius^2 - (x - a)^2 )) + b
        
    omega -- angular velocity = angular displacement / time
    describes how many rotation(s) in 1s : ? rad / s
    OR
    use how much time for 1 revolution : 2pi rad / ? s
    */
    Path path = new Path();
    // path.addCircle(x, y, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);
    path.moveTo(center_x + radius, center_y);
        
    for (float i = center_x + radius; i >= center_x - radius; --i) {  // center-x +- radius
        // x : right -> left
        // y : anti-clockwise
        path.lineTo(i, (long) - Math.sqrt(radius * radius - (i - center_x) * (i - center_x)) + center_y);
    }
    
    for (float i = center_x - radius; i <= center_x + radius; ++i) {  // center-x +- radius
        // x : left -> right
        // y : anti-clockwise
        path.lineTo(i, (long) Math.sqrt(radius * radius - (i - center_x) * (i - center_x)) + center_y);
    }

    // and the draw in canvas with path part
}
```

then the `path` will move from the right ( 0 radian ) , up ( anti-clockwise ) ( to pi/2 rad , pi rad , 3pi/2 rad , 2pi rad at the end ) and complete the path of the circle with center (`center_x`, `center_y`) and radius `radius`

// you may ignore the variable `omega` here lol

hope it helps